# New York street netowrk

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

The road network of New York can be modelled as a directed graph with both bidirectional and
unidirectional edges. 
Does it have a Euler path?

Answer (score 1):

No, is not. Because since there are also unidirectional edges, it could be that $d(x,y) \ne d(y,x)$.

Comment: Is that because you can take a one way street from x->y, but can't return on that same street y->x?

Comment: Yes. It could be that to go from $y$ to $x$ you have to go for a longer way. 
Take for example and equilateral triangle with vertexes $x, y, z$ and with unitadirectional edges:
$x -> y, y-> z, z -> x$. Clearly $d(x,y) > d(y,x)$